# Can proxy server use to change COS or DSCP fields in traffic packet

Tags: proxy

I'm looking for a proxy service that can change the CoS and DSCP  fields in a traffic packet. There are proxy services that can change HTTP content and headers.

It should ideally run on Linux or Windows, and preferably be opensource.

Comment: Thanks, that helps narrowing down things (I've integrated it with your question body so it's not missed easily). Remains the price question: open source does not necessarily imply free-of-cost, even if we're speaking about free/libre software ;)